# Return only checked (selected) items in PHP

Tags: php, input, checkbox, foreach

I am having trouble returning only checked items from a list of items. Instead of returning only the checked items, I get the full list of checkboxes: selected or not.

I have a form that returns a number of list of items with checkboxes. It seems to be working correctly, saving the users preference and correctly assigning `checked="checked"` to items they pick.

It is generated as follows:

```
foreach ($this->item as $code => $value) {
    $checked = $this->settings['item'][$code] ? "checked='checked'" : '';
    $output .= "<label style=\"margin-left: 20px;\"><input type='checkbox' {$checked} name='options[item][{$code}]'/>{$this->item[$code]}</label><br />\n\r";
}
```

I want to return ONLY the values of the selected checkboxes.

This is what I have been trying:

```
foreach ($_POST['items'] as $value) {
    echo "the value are: ".$value;
}
```

This returns all of the items instead of only the selected ones.

I have also tried:

```
$item = $this->item;
foreach($item as $code) {
    print $code;
}
```

This also returns all checked and non checked items.

Can anybody point me to where the problem is?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking, but I assume that you want the ones which are previously checked. So, try this:

```
foreach ($_POST['items'] as $code => $value) {
    if ($this->settings['item'][$code]) {
        echo "the value are: ".$value;
    }
}
```